# Segmentation fault on writing char to char* address

Tags: c++, c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I've got problem with my little C program. Maybe you could help me.

```
char* shiftujVzorku(char* text, char* pattern, int offset){
    char* pom = text;
    int size = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(*(text + size) != '\0'){
        size++;
    }
    while(*(pom + index) != '\0'){
        if(overVzorku(pom + index, pattern)){
            while(*pattern != '\0'){
                //vyment *pom s *pom + offset
                if(pom + index + offset < text + size){
                    char x = *(pom + index + offset);
                    char y = *(pom + index);
                    int adresa = *(pom + index + offset);
                    *(pom + index + offset) = y;   // SEGMENTATION FAULT
                    *(pom + index) = x;   
                    //*pom  = *pom - *(pom + offset);
                    //*(pom + offset) = *(pom + offset) + *pom;
                    //*pom = *(pom + offset) - *pom;
                }
                else{
                    *pom  = *pom - *(pom + offset - size);
                    *(pom + offset - size) = *(pom + offset - size) + *pom;
                    *pom = *(pom + offset - size) - *pom;
                }
                pattern++;
            }
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Isn't important what's the programm doing. Maybe there's lot of bugs. But, why do I get SEGMENTATION FAULT (for destination see code) at this line? I'm, trying to write some char value to memory space, with help of address "pom + offset + index". Thanks for everything helpful. :)

Comment: Perhaps the caller isn't passing in a pointer to read-only memory. Perhaps the caller isn't passing in a pointer to *enough* read-only memory. Who knows?

Comment: that code hurt my eyes when I read it. I'd start with breaking up the code into logical parts, put those in seperate functions, then check again..

Comment: You can use a debugger, like gdb to analyze the problem. I think it is more important for you to learn how to solve this issues than to receive an answer from us.

Comment: I always like a good, clear name for a function... shiftujVzorku really fits the bill :-)

Comment: lol @Francesco ... likely it is good and clear name in his own mother tongue language :)

Comment: @Francesco: btw. "shiftujVzorku" is "shiftPattern" in slovak (although, "shiftuj" is not slovak, just taken from english). "overVzorku" is "checkPattern". Personally I like better names which better reveal intention and use prepositions to clarify meaning of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance calling the code like this:

```
shiftujVzorku( "foobar", "xx", 0 );
```

If so, your code attempts to write to a character literal, which is illegal in C. You should rather do:

```
char buf[] = "foobar";
shiftujVzorku( buf, "xx", 0 );
```

Comment: A comment on conversion from "char const*" to "char*" may be useful to help explain why it compiled but then crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the address that pom+size+index points to is not a memory location that your program is allowed to write to.

Things to check: Is 'text' a legitimate buffer of some sort? It's just passed in, so there's no clue in the code given where it came from. Did you malloc it? Is it on the stack somewhere? Also, is it actually NUL terminated when it comes in?

Comment: calling this function:

    char* a = "abcd";
    char* b = "b";
    shiftujVzorku(a, b, 1);

in dbg mode, I can see that address "pom+size+index" sees something inside string "abcd", 
char x = *(pom + index + offset); //gets  characted 'c'
I think there's no reason to be out of accessible memory space.

Answer (score 0):

I think it DOES matter what the program is doing, or at least what parameters the function takes. Right now, it looks like the problem is that you loop `index` until `pom + index` points to the end of the string, but then you try to access `pom + index + offset`, which is after the end of the string. Or perhaps `offset` is negative?

Comment: params are definitely fine :) pls see my previous comment for detailed infos.

Comment: problem was, that from declaration of: char *x = "....", x is pointer to const sequence of characters, You cannost write or change one of these chars using *x

Comment: @Lukas: It's a bit late, but good to know that you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What a mess!

Anyway, the problem comes from offset I think. You don't even check that *(pom + index + offset) is memory location you can use. Maybe it is after the '\0' of your text.

You should compare size and index+offset before trying to use *(pom + index + offset).